# How to piece together String using file reader and char array

Tags: java, arrays, file

Wrote a file in another class and now I'm trying to piece together the file into a JLabel, so I need to convert the name in the file into a string. Using FileReader and a char array to separate each character into an array to be put together in the JLabel.

I'm getting this error on `NamePieces[x] = (char)nr;`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at clients.initialize(clients.java:197)
        at clients.<init>(clients.java:72)
```

This is the code that I want to read the file:

```
try(FileReader nameReader = new FileReader(NamePath)) {
        int nr = nameReader.read();
        int x = 0;
        while(nr != -1) {
            namePieces[x] = (char)nr;
            nr = nameReader.read();
            x++;
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    catch (IOException e1) {}

    String name = String.valueOf(namePieces[0]) + namePieces[1];
```

Doesn't work

Comment: I guess your problem occurs because namePieces is not initialized

Comment: Your error indicates that `namePieces` array is empty. I couldn't find where you define and initialize `namePieces` in the code you posted. Please [edit] your post and add the definition of `namePieces`.

Comment: Don't use a `char[]`: you can't resize it as you read more and more data. Use a `StringBuilder`, this is pretty much exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your problem occurs because `namePieces` is not initialized. As was already mentioned in the comments, you should not use `char[]` as a container for your characters (because in real world you won't know the length of the files' contents every time, so you will probably need to resize your container), it is way more better to use `StringBuilder`, provided by Java standard library. It will protect you from getting out of bounds.

```
StringBuilder namePieces = new StringBuilder();
File file = new File(filePath);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),
                                                  Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
int c;
while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
    namePieces.append((char) c);
}

String nameString = namePieces.toString(); // Use this string as a complete array of needed characters
```

As you see I changed an approach by using not only `StringBuilder`, but also `BufferedReader`. However, for your task you can leave `FileReader` as it is. Just consider appending characters to builder.

Answer (score 0):

If your file just contains a String there is a straightforward way to read it:

```
public String readMyFile( String fileName) throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);

    return Files.readAllLines(path).get(0);
}
```